# "Cannot find symbol variable BuildConfig" with multiple source folders

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I'm working with a project that have a lot of legacy code. I need to keep separated the "old code" from the new one. So I created the following directories:

```
-ProjectRoot
  -app
    -src
      -main
        -java
        -java_legacy
        -res
        -res_legacy
```

And added the following block to my `build.gradle`:

```
android {
        .....
        sourceSets {
            main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/java_legacy'
            main.res.srcDirs += 'src/main/res_legacy'
        }
}
```

But when I try to run the app I get the error:

```
error: cannot find symbol variable BuildConfig
```

The file where the error is shown seems random and does NOT use nor import the class BuildConfig.

If I empty the code inside the file generating the error, it appears in another (pseudo-random) file.

How can I solve this?

Note: I tried, `"Build/CleanProject"`, `"File/ Invalidate Caches / Restart ..."`, 'Synchronize gradle build"  but the error persists

Comment: try building your project, as long as it's not built, it won't be accessible

Comment: I get this error when I try to build/mage/run the project =(

Comment: Did you find any answer? I had this issue and waste hours on it and still can't find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

This might help others who wasted few hours resolving a similar issue. Search for occurrences of BuildConfig and see if the right one has been imported. Strangely the compiler didn't catch an obvious wrong import but pointed at a random line of code.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and it turned out I had two directories in `src/main/java/com/<app name>` - one was old and didn't match the bundle id. Removing this fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

As an advice, try it so:

```
sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/java_legacy']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res_legacy']
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Clicke synchronize, on the right side of save after gradle sync

Comment: Tried all kinds of clean/synchronize but doesn't work